# How can I display custom view same as when long pressed on search icon on below image?

Tags: java, android, tooltip

[image: This is image]
How can I dislay custom view same as when long pressed on search icon on below image?

[image: my code]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're looking for a tooltip. https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip

Comment: Post you Java and XML in https://paste.ofcode.org/ instead of post images

Comment: @InsaneCat Thanks for your suggestion The problem has already been solved

Comment: user directly  TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(ivUser, "Mark as done"); into OnCreate() and remove LongClick method

Comment: See use like this : @mohasafi https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811197/3974530

Answer (score 3):

the feature you want to implement is called "Tooltip". Android default provides us to add a Tooltip to the View.

```
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(imgSearch, "Your tooltip string here")
```

// "imgSearch" is your View/button/anything you want to add Tooltip to when user Long Presses it.

Comment: @mohasafi Please try this solution, for this you need not use any 3rd party library, and if it helps, you can mark it Approved/Correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define **title** property in your menu file like below.

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_call"
    android:title="Call"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
</menu>
```

If you not using menu, then just add below code into your onCreate method.

---

```
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(your_view_id, "Your message here")
```

Comment: In my application I do not use menu

Comment: @mohasafi,
If you used any view for the icon then you need to use below code.
-------------

`TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(your_view_id, "Your message here")`

Comment: Can you please provide your code of XML and Java file. and also what error you are getting. so I can go through it.

Comment: I used Android X as well as API above O and the code did not work

Comment: Are you using kotlin or Java.

Comment: Did you add below gradle to your code.
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`

Comment: ........ I use java and used this implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Comment: I need both java and xml.

Comment: @ DipakSharma Can you talk to me through the email because I want to upload the code pictures to you

Comment: @InsaneCat  Thank you my friend your answers are correct but I do not want to use the library also do not use the menu

Comment: @mohasafi My answer is not only for Menu anyways if you need any held then let me know

Comment: @mohasafi,
You can attach the picture in your question by updating it.

Comment: Remove the Long click listener. we don't required it. Just add that line into your onCreate Method.

Put this line into your onCreate method

`TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(ivUser, "profile")`

Comment: @mohasafi, You can make that comment as a useful.

Comment: @DipakSharma  How can I make your comment useful ?